# Which body of the Buddha belongs to the Buddha nature?

Tags: mahayana, buddha-nature, trikaya

Which body of the Buddha belongs to the Buddha nature?

I suppose all three, but I would be interested to hear otherwise.

Comment: probably going to delete the question, cos it may just generate confusion (in both me and you) about the term "belongs"

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "Buddha nature"? I think it means:

Anyone is Buddha, as soon as he stops to generate vexations.

That fact can be described as: "We all are Buddha by nature, we only differ from Buddha in maintaining some mental processes".

Therefore, the term "Buddha nature" is applicable to sentient beings, not to metaphysical concepts of reality like Trikaya.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i don't think the trikaya is always a metaphysical doctrine though.